# Can't edit script in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Whenever I write a script inside Google Chrome using the Developer Tools > Sources > Snippets, I'm not able to edit the script content after I hit run

The Console generates the log, but clicking on the script panel has no effect. I'm able to select the content, but that's all. The only way to clear the content or type again is deleting the current snippet file and/or creating an empty one

Some people said it could be due to one of my extensions, but I've already tested in a new Chrome window logged as a Guest user and the output was the same. It happens on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 as well

Comment: Really strange. If you open an Ctrl+Shift+N anonymous session, can you edit the snippet ? Also, does the normal devtools console work for you ? I couldn't reproduce on a mac.

Comment: Is the browser version up to date ? Have you tried to reinstall Chrome ?

Comment: I can't edit the snippet in an anonymous session either. The normal devtools console works, as far as I know. And, yes, the browser version is up to date in both Windows and Ubuntu

Comment: What is your Chrome version ? Have you tried reinstalling it ? Something you're describing isn't what you think it is.